# Error when presenting AlertView on dismissing MFMessageController

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uialertview, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am struggling with view hierarchy but I cannot figure out what is going wrong here. I try to send a message (`MFMessageComposeViewController`). I would like to show an `alertView` depending on the success (or not) with the help of delegate methods. The alertView is displayed when the message is cancelled but I get this error when the message is sent:

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x153b3c00>)
```

It looks like as if the completion block was called before the `MFMessageComposeView` was completey dismissed (or deallocated) when the message is sent (as if there was still something running behind the scenes), but not when it is cancelled.
If it can help:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    int tag;

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        {
            tag = 1;
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        }
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            tag = 2;
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
        {
            tag = 3;
            NSLog(@"Sent");
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self alertSMSMessageWithTag:tag];
    }];
}

- (void)alertSMSMessageWithTag:(int)tag {

    UIAlertController *alertController;

    if (tag == 1) { // cancelled
        alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message cancelled" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];
    }
    if (tag == 2) { // Failed
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message failed" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];
    }
    if (tag == 3) { // sent
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message sent" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];
    }
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If anyone could help me...

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising `UIAlertController` in a proper way. You are using same variable name alertController which is public to

```
if (tag == 3) {
}
```

but not public to the method. And you are using same variable name which is public to method  `UIAlertController *alertController;`
 `[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];` is accessing public to method variable i.e `UIAlertController *alertController;` which you have correctly initialised for tag 1. I would suggest you to use following code -

```
- (void)alertSMSMessageWithTag:(int)tag {

     UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:ok];
    if (tag == 1) { // cancelled
       alertController.title = @"Message cancelled";

    }
    if (tag == 2) { // Failed
        alertController.title = @"Message failed";
    }
    if (tag == 3) { // sent
       alertController.title = @"Message sent";

    }
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope its helpful.